# Mogenerator "--base-class-import" not including #import

Tags: xcode, core-data, mogenerator

I am trying to import a file in all of my Mogenerator generated classes using `--base-class-import`

Here is the Run script:

```
 mogenerator -m Project/Data/Model/model.xcdatamodeld -O Project/Data/Managed\ Object --template-var arc=true --base-class-import "Project/Categories/NSManagedObject+Extras.h"
```

I've tried without the full path (just the class name), and also with single quotes, and no quotes:

```
 mogenerator -m Project/Data/Model/model.xcdatamodeld -O Project/Data/Managed\ Object --template-var arc=true --base-class-import "NSManagedObject+Extras.h"
```

However this doesn't regenerate the files.

Everything works fine without `--base-class-import`:

```
mogenerator -m Project/Data/Model/model.xcdatamodeld -O Project/Data/Managed\ Object --template-var arc=true
```

What am I missing or what else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem.

I think the author's original idea was to import base class from a different header, not the for the `NSManagedobject`'s category.

And what we want mainly from mogenerator is auto and `subclass`, for its flexibility on comparison with `category`.

And, if you insist on category:

You can do with:

`mogenerator -m Project/Data/Model/model.xcdatamodeld -O Project/Data/Managed\ Object --template-var arc=true --base-class NSManagedObject --base-class-import "NSManagedObject+Extras.h"`

To denote with NSManagedObject as `--base-class` to bypass this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up using a base class and importing the category there.